# INSERT data from append script

Tags: javascript, php

I have a problem.
here is my php & HTML:

```
<?php
          if ($_POST['btn_tambah'] == 'tambah') {

          $sub_lapangan = $_POST['sub_lapangan'];
          $SQL = "SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT as IDLapangan FROM information_schema.tables WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'ta' AND TABLE_NAME = 'lapangan';";
          $res = mysql_query($SQL, $link);
          $row = mysql_fetch_object($res);
          $tambah1 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO sub_lapangan(nama,status,id_lapangan) VALUES('".$sub_lapangan."',1,$row->IDLapangan);");
    }
?>

<HTML><BODY>
 <div class="row">
       <div class="form-group" id="sub_lapangan">
          <div class="col-lg-3"><label>Nama Sub-Lapangan :</label></div>
          <div class="col-lg-2">
             <input type="text" name="sub_lapangan" class="form-control"  required>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-1">
           <a onclick="tambahSubBaru()" class ="btn btn-info"> <i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
          </div>
       </div>
 </div>
 <div id="sembunyisub">
 </div>
</BODY></HTML>
```

Here is my script:

```
 var count = 0;
        function tambahSubBaru() {
            count += 1;
            if (count > 15) {
                alert("Maksimal Untuk Tambah Sub Lapangan adalah 15 Sub Lapangan");
            }
            else {
                $('#sembunyisub').append(
                '<div class="row" id="barisbarusub' + count + '">'
                    + '<div class="form-group">'
                    + '<div class="col-lg-3">'
                    + '</div>'
                    + '<div class="col-lg-2">'
                    + '<input id="subku' + count + '" type="text" class="form-control" name="sub_lapangan" required>'
                    + '</div>'
                    + '<div class="col-lg-1">'
                    + '<a class ="btn btn-warning" onclick="hapusSub(' + count + ')"> <i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a>'
                    + '</div>'
                    + '</div>'
                    + '</div>'
            );
            }
        }

        function hapusSub(row) {
            $('#barisbarusub' + row).remove();
        }
```

Here is the pic:

[image]
[image]

So the scenario is, when i click the "plus" button, it will show up the second textbox. I want to insert them into database. but when i try to insert, the SECOND textbox is succedded to insert in database. but the FIRST textbox doesn't insert to database. 
How can i insert the FIRST textbox?
to show up the second textbox, i use `.append` in javascript.
help me please. I aprreciated the answer. many thank you. :)

Comment: Your form has multiple inputs with the same name?  You might want to check the form post in your debugging tools to make sure all of the values are even being posted to the server in the first place.  Perhaps posting an array of values might be what you want?

Comment: As an added note, do not use `mysql_*` methods, they are unsafe and have been removed from PHP 7. Use PDO or `mysqli` with prepared statements.

Comment: @apokryfos so, when i run this code on the computer that have php 7, it's not working ?

Comment: If you setup your server using PHP 7 , this code will not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to loop through your fields in PHP. Therefore you have to create an Array-input-element with [] after the name.

HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="sub_lapangan[]" class="form-control"  required> <!-- Add [] to your field name for creating an Array-->
```

JS:

```
+ '<input id="subku' + count + '" type="text" class="form-control" name="sub_lapangan[]" required>' //The same in you dynamic input field
```

PHP: Loop through you fields (Array)

```
if ($_POST['btn_tambah'] == 'tambah') {    
  $sub_lapangan = $_POST['sub_lapangan'];
  $SQL = "SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT as IDLapangan FROM information_schema.tables WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'ta' AND TABLE_NAME = 'lapangan';";
  $res = mysql_query($SQL, $link);
  $row = mysql_fetch_object($res);

  $fields = $_POST['sub_lapangan']; //Your Array
  foreach($fields as $field => $value) { 
    $tambah1 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO sub_lapangan(nama,status,id_lapangan) VALUES('".$value."',1,$row->IDLapangan);");
  }
}
```

Comment: wow. It's working man. many thank you.
but what is $value? i'm sorry, i'm newbie.

Comment: It's the value for the current field in the loop. Take a look here: [foreach](http://php.net/manual/de/control-structures.foreach.php)

Comment: hi, i'm ask again, what if input type file? i have an error "invalid argument supplied for foreach()". 

$fields = "gallery/" . $_FILES['gambar']['name'];

foreach($fields as $field => $value) { 
    $tambah1 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO sub_lapangan(nama,status,id_lapangan) VALUES('".$value."',1,$row->IDLapangan);");
  }

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
'INSERT INTO sub_lapangan(nama,status,id_lapangan) VALUES("'.$sub_lapangan.'","1","'.$row->IDLapangan.'")'
```

Comment: i've update the description. i'm sorry. it's typo. hehe
so, the second textbox is inserted. but the first textbox doesn't inserted.

Comment: you are using same names to both boxes, second is overwriting the value of first